# Pandas Find Max High with variable length when condition met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe of close to 1 million records with columns including the cond1, height, distance (which is the number of rows forward).  What I would like to do is iterate over the dataframe and when the cond1 = True get the maximum height from the current index + 1 to the number of rows as per the distance column else the value is 0.  The values would be stored in a new column df['highest'].  Since I have 1 million rows I really didn't want to loop through the dataframe as per below which does give the correct results but super slow.  Any help is appreciated.

```
results = []
for idx in df.index:
    if df.cond1.iloc[idx]:
        results.append(df.height.iloc[idx+1 : (idx + df.distance.iloc[idx]+1)].max())
    else:
        results.append(0)

df['highest'] = results
```

## Results

```
   cond1  height  distance  highest
0   True    1.66         6     1.91
1  False    1.77         1     0.00
2  False    1.91         8     0.00
3  False    1.82         5     0.00
4  False    1.58         1     0.00
5  False    1.73         9     0.00
6   True    1.41         2     1.55
7  False    1.51         4     0.00
8   True    1.55         1     1.50
9  False    1.50         4     0.00
```

## Create test data

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[True, 1.66, 6], [False, 1.77, 1], [False, 1.91, 8], [False,1.82, 5], [False,1.58, 1], [False, 1.73, 9], [True, 1.41,2], [False, 1.51, 4], [True, 1.55, 1], [False, 1.5,4]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cond1', 'height', 'distance'])

   cond1  height  distance
0   True    1.66         6
1  False    1.77         1
2  False    1.91         8
3  False    1.82         5
4  False    1.58         1
5  False    1.73         9
6   True    1.41         2
7  False    1.51         4
8   True    1.55         1
9  False    1.50         4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a [custom window](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html#custom-window-rolling), where you will be able to set the step of the window each time:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer

class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):

    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed):
        
        # start from the next index each time
        start = np.arange(num_values, dtype=np.int64) + 1
        
        # stop after n indices, where n is determined from the 'distance' column each time
        end = start + np.array(self.step, dtype=np.int64)
        
        return start, end

indexer = CustomIndexer(step=df['distance'])

df['highest'] = np.where(
    df['cond1'],
    df['height'].rolling(indexer).max(),
    0
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  The distance column is what needs to be used to to determine how many rows forward you need to look for the max high of the height column.  If you use this new data set data = [[True, 1.66, 3], [False, 1.77, 1], [True, 1.91, 2], [False,1.82, 5], [False,1.58, 1], [True, 1.73, 3], [True, 1.41,2], [False, 1.51, 4], [True, 1.55, 1], [False, 1.5,4]] you will see it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnHolmes does the updated answer solve your problem? :)

Comment: thanks for updating let me check it out and see

Comment: @JohnHolmes Have you checked? Is everything alright? I kinda liked your problem and now I'm curious if it worked out :p